# Delete all divs except a div with a specific class?

Tags: php, replace, preg-match-all

If i have this setup on website 1:

```
<div class="awesomeContent">
    <div>
        Information goes here...
    </div>
    <div>
        Information goes here...
    </div>
    <div>
        Information goes here...
    </div>
</div>
```

If i then use this on website 2:

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents('http://website.com/hello);
preg_match_all ("/<div class=\"awesomeContent\">([^`]*?)<\/div>/", $data, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

I want it to post:

```
<div class="awesomeContent">
    <div>
        Information goes here...
    </div>
    <div>
        Information goes here...
    </div>
    <div>
        Information goes here...
    </div>
</div>
```

but all i get is

```
<div class="awesomeContent">
    <div>
        Information goes here...
    </div>
```

How do I do this better?

Comment: Use DOMDocument to process HTML! Don't use regex.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use dom parsing here something like

```
$parsedHtml = simplexml_load_string($data);
print_r($parsedHtml)`
```

But Still the solution to your problem is to 
replace

```
 "/<div class=\"awesomeContent\">([^`]*?)<\/div>/"
```

with

```
  "/<div class=\"awesomeContent\">([^`]*)<\/div>/"
```

because you are using class in your pattern which is there only in first div

Comment: How does "/<div.*>([^`]*?)<\/div>/" help me if I got a website with lots of tags beside this area, and this is the only area I want.?

Comment: @AlexWestergaard ohh .. sorry my bad ..Try removing lazy search then.. what is happening now here is you are using lazy search and so it is getting stopped at first </div > which is after 'information goes here'